# Is it possible for a mailto to be changed on the frontend with HTML?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova

I don't think this can be done, but I have a PhoneGap app that I am the main developer on. It basically captures form details into an email, and then submits them.

Is it possible for the email address of the mailto link to be changed without modifying the code? E.g., A mail settings page where the user could enter an email address to be put there, to be used in the mailto.

Comment: What i read is.  "can my app change settings without coding it into the app".  My answer is no.  Othewise, if my answer was not what you expected, im not sure what you mean then :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "without modifying the code"?

Comment: Without having to change the code every time the address changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the mailto url with javascript

but you have the mail composer plugin to send mails, it's better than using mailto